# Checking whether two Boost.MPL sequences contain the same types in any order

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming

Is there a straightforward method of checking whether two MPL sequences (such as `boost::mpl::set`) contain the same elements regardless of their order?

For example, consider the following:

```
#include <boost/mpl/set.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::mpl::set<int, double, bool> X;
    typedef boost::mpl::set<double, bool, int> Y;

    // We'd want this to pass, but obviously it won't ...
    BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((boost::mpl::equals<X, Y>));
}
```

In principle, what one could do is write some boilerplate to check that (i) X and Y have the same size (use `boost::mpl::size`) and (ii) verify that every element of X is contained in Y (use `boost::mpl::contains`). An alternative would be to somehow sort both sequences to some "canonical order" and then checking if they are equal, but I don't know if there is functionality for this.

But I wonder: is there a function that already does what we want in Boost.MPL (or anywhere in Boost)?

Comment: I suppose we could repeatedly attempt to remove types of `X` from `Y`, and then when we've finished, we can verify if `Y` is empty

Comment: MPL supports sorting of types, if memory serves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <boost/mpl/and.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/not.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/set.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/contains.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>

namespace mpl=boost::mpl;

//template <typename Seq1, typename Seq2>
//using unordered_equal = mpl::equal<Seq1,Seq2,mpl::and_<mpl::contains<Seq2,mpl::_1>, mpl::contains<Seq1,mpl::_2> > >;

template <typename Seq1, typename Seq2>
struct unordered_equal : mpl::equal<Seq1,Seq2,mpl::and_<mpl::contains<Seq2,mpl::_1>, mpl::contains<Seq1,mpl::_2> > >
{};

int main()
{
    typedef mpl::set<int, double, bool> X;
    typedef mpl::set<double, bool, int> Y;
    typedef mpl::set<double, bool> Z;

    // We'd want this to pass, but obviously it won't ...
    BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((unordered_equal<X, Y>));
    BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((mpl::not_<unordered_equal<X,Z> >));
}
```

Comment: You can of course change the predicate to check for the conditions expressed in your question...